# Kotlin init not picking up value from @Value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I want to initialise a member variable from a value I pick from ENV but it is not available in init block as it gets picked up after object initialisation

```
private lateinit var needValueHere: String
@Value("\${CLIENT_ID:NA}")
private val CLIENT_ID: String = ""

init {
    this.needValueHere = this.CLIENT_ID    
}
```

This is a simplified version of the actual problem.
I have verified the value is available in the member functions.

Comment: Is there a reason you need it to be a `lateinit var` member variable rather than a constructor parameter? With Spring Boot constructor parameters can be injected too, and then they're available in `init`.

Comment: Yes I load the context from a third party service before initialising it

Comment: PS I figured that out already and have worked out the solution.Thanks for the help though:)

Answer (score 1):

Your object is constructing by the following way:

- Create object (e.g. call constructor)
- Via reflection: put dependencies (e.g. fill values under @Autowired, @Value and other annotations).

Your init block is part of constructor, e.g. all Spring-related items aren't initialized here.

How you can fix this:

- Extract properties to the type-safe configuration (please see [official docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties))
- Use notation of class like below.
- Create `private lateinit var` field and don't call it until Spring initialization finishing (this is useful for integration tests, e.g. test methods start only after full warmup). Another option - use [kotlin lazy notation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-lazy/index.html). However whole this item couldn't be named as "good code".

```
class MyService(@Value("\${CLIENT_ID:NA}") private val needValueHere: String) {
   /* */
}
```